# TFS Sprint change order Drag&Drop

Tags: tfs

I noticed that I can change the order of the PBIs of the current sprint on visualstudio.com via Drag&Drop. At work we use TFS 2013 on our own server (I think the newest version Update 4) and that's not possible. Both use the SCRUM template.

Is this a configuration issue? It would help a lot if this would work at our own TFS too. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features available in VSO are beyond that of TFS 2013 update 4. The feature that you are referring to is planned for TFS 2015.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/news/release-archive-vso

For most customers, regardless of size, I recommend moving to VSO to get access to the latest and greatest features as they become available.